# swift package --verbose generate-xcodeproj giving error: reachedTimeLimit

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm attempting to generate an Xcode project and am getting:
error: reachedTimeLimit

Unfortunately I don't see a lot of help googling this error nor does there appear to be a way to extend whatever the current time limit is from the command line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hardcoded 10 second time limit for package resolving baked into SPM - see the code in [DependencyResolver.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/PackageGraph/DependencyResolver.swift).

Line 1365 has `let timeLimit = 10`, and there is no way of changing this externally, except of course building your own version of SPM with a higher timeout.

I haven't dug deep enough into the resolver algorithm, but it seems that your dependency tree is pretty complex for the resolving to take so long.